# Difference between export/import and backup/restore in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, database-backups

Can someone explain what are the differences between export/import and backup/restore in Oracle DB? And when should I use each one of them? And why does "import database dump" process take very long time to execute?

Comment: Reading the documentation is always a good start -  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/bradv/index.html
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RMAN backups create physical backups of the data files by copying them block by block. It doesn't care what's actually in a given block, though it will copy only those blocks that have or have had data, and ignore the empty blocks.  It also keeps metadata about those blocks, so that on a RESTORE it can correctly reconstruct the data files from the backed-up blocks.  RMAN backups can be used to restore/recover a database that has completely gone up in smoke. It can also process incremental backups and archivelogs to completely recover to any point in time covered by those incrementals and archivelogs.

Export creates a binary file that is essentially a bunch of CREATE  and INSERT statements, to reproduce what was exported.  The accompanying IMPORT will then read that dump file and replay all of the CREATE and INSERT statements contained therein. Import requires an operating database to receive and process those statements. And it is strictly a 'single point in time - the time at which the export was executed.

RAMAN backups are for disaster recovery.  Export/import is for saving selected data/objects at a given point in time.

Comment: Many thanks for your perfect answer. 
As I understood, backup process copies database files as they are.
In other side, export process generates new file that contents database structure (tables, views, stored procedures, users, … etc.) and data using sql commands (create , alter, insert).
Therefore, import database dump means that system recreates database by run sql commands that saved in database dump.

Comment: That may explain why import database dump takes a long time to execute ? because every time system inserts new row, system checks each row data (database I have contain millions of rows) regarding to table's constraints.

Comment: It's not just the checking of constraints on row insert.  It's the index maintenance, the generation and maintenance of redo, the checking of rollback, possible allocation of extents, etc, etc, etc.  And there are things that export/import will not create. It won't create a database. It won't create data files.

Comment: Also, in thinking about rman 'copying' data file, it's not like an OS copy command simply creating a binary copy of the file.  RMAN copies the _blocks_ of a file, essentially de-constructing it. And if a particular block has never actually contained data, it doesn't even bother copying it.  On restore, re reconstructs the file

Answer (score 2):

You are right, there are similarities between export/import and backup/restore, but also big differences.

If you think not of a database, but your laptop (or other local computer), you would "restore" the data in case a disaster happens from "backup"s you hopefully have made. And you would "export" some or more data to an USB stick to "import" it to some other computer, or keep it as a snapshot for a long time.

Both tools are specialised for their purpose. For instance, you can say exactly what schema, users, tables, even rows should be exported and where they will be imported agein. For instance, backups are normally split in a usually weekly full backup und usually daily backups that store only the latest changes, which makes it very fast to backup and to recover data.

Frankly, I always am puzzled about the slow speed of an import. Basically it is only slightly faster than replaying all the inserts that ever happened. However, there are tricks to make it faster, look into parallel loading, transportable tablespaces etc.